# Retrieve a Reference value from one Firestore document then write it to another document reference field

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to (1) retrieve a reference field value from a doc in `collection_a` and write it to a doc in `collection_b`.  However, I get a full `DocumentReference` object with lots of info rather than just the document reference path/string I want.

```ts
// Function executes {onCreate} of a new Firestore document in {collection_a}
exports.createNotifications = functions.firestore
  .document(`collection_a/{docId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap: any, context: any) => { 
    const newRecord = snap.data();

      // Retrieve {myReferenceField} from {collection_a} collection.
      const myReferenceField: string = newRecord.myReferenceField
      
      // Query {collection_b} collection for docs where {myReferenceField} = the previously retrieved reference (above).
      const collection_b_ref = db.collection('collection_b');
      const collection_b_snapshot = await collection_b_ref.where('myReferenceField', '==', myReferenceField).get();

      // Loop through retrieved documents from {collection_b}, writing the retrieved reference to the {myTargetReferenceField}.
      collection_b_snapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
        var newDocumentWrite = {
          myTargetReferenceField: db.doc('target_collection/' + myReferenceField),
        }

        return admin.firestore().collection('notifications').add(newDocumentWrite)

      }); 
    }
  });
```

The `myTargetReferenceField: db.doc('target_collection/' + myReferenceField)` line returns an object of `myTargetReferenceField: target_collection/[object Object]` rather than just the reference path of `target_collection/123456sample_ref123456` I want.

My console shows `myTargetReferenceField` as a full object (as below) rather than just the slash-delimited reference which is what I want.

**Console Output for {MyTargetReferenceField} - I only want the ref path**
** See the {_path: ResourcePath} in output below (replaced {teams} for purpose of this ticket **

[image: console log]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of your question, so will answer the two most likely asks below.

---

If you want to get the path to the `DocumentReference` from a field, you can call the [`path` property](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#path) on it.

---

Firestore's `get()` operation always reads complete documents, not just some fields from it.

To get only some fields from a document, the Node.js SDK has a [`select` method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#select) that you can call on either a `Query` or a `CollectionReference`.

Comment: Thank you Frank.

I am trying to retrieve a string containing the value from a Firestore reference field called {myReferenceField} as below...

```
const newRecord = snap.data();
const myReferenceField: string = newRecord.myReferenceField
```
But I can't work out how to reference the path property from the returned object?

When you say 'you can call the path property' (forgive my ignorance) - how do I do that?

Comment: If you have a `DocumentReference` object (say `ref`), you can get the path from it by `const path = ref.path`.